# Is there an easy way to parse a (lambda expression) string into an Action delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parsing, expression-trees

I have a method that alters an "Account" object based on the action delegate passed into it:

```
public static void AlterAccount(string AccountID, Action<Account> AccountAction) {
  Account someAccount = accountRepository.GetAccount(AccountID);
  AccountAction.Invoke(someAccount);
  someAccount.Save();
}
```

This works as intended...

```
AlterAccount("Account1234", a => a.Enabled = false);
```

...but now what I'd like to try and do is have a method like this:

```
public static void AlterAccount(string AccountID, string AccountActionText) {
  Account someAccount = accountRepository.GetAccount(AccountID);
  Action<Account> AccountAction = MagicLibrary.ConvertMagically<Action<Account>>(AccountActionText);
  AccountAction.Invoke(someAccount);
  someAccount.Save();
}
```

It can then be used like:

```
AlterAccount("Account1234", "a => a.Enabled = false");
```

to disable account "Account1234".

I've had a look at the [linq dynamic query library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), which seems to do more or less what I want but for Func type delegates, and my knowledge of Expression trees etc isn't quite good enough to work out how to achieve what I want.

Is there an easy way to do what I want, or do I need to learn expressions properly and write a load of code?

(The reason I want to do this is to allow an easy way of bulk updating account objects from a powershell script where the user can specify a lambda expression to perform the changes.)

Comment: the hard way would be to use System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod and generate IL code. however, in this case it may just be easier to accept a syntax that specifies a property name and a value, and have a reflection bases property setter.

Comment: Yes, I've thought of that, but I think that would rule out some potentially powerful things, like being able to call AlterAccount("Account1234", "a=>a.Enabled = !a.Enabled"); (not sure why you'd want to do that specifically, but there's other more sensible examples)

Comment: I had a good laugh reading this: `MagicLibrary.ConvertMagically`

Answer (score 4):

The Dynamic LINQ library is a fine choice, as it'll generate expressions you can compile to code in a lightweight fashion.

The example you provided actually produces a boolean -- so you should be able to ask for a Func and it might sort it out.

Edit: This of course is wrong, as Expressions don't have assignment in them at all.

So, another potential way is to take two lambdas. One to find the property you want, one to provide a value:

(a => a.AccountId), (a => true)

Then use reflection to set the property referenced in the first lambda with the result of the second one. Hackish, but it's still probably lightweight compared to invoking the C# compiler.

This way you don't have to do much codegen yourself - the expressions you get will contain most everything you need.

Comment: I think...If I was doing "a => a.Enabled == false" then it would work, but I'm doing "a => a.Enabled = false" - I want to do that action on the Account, so I don't think it'll work without some modification.

Comment: Bah you're right. It works for funcs: Func<bool> exp = () => test = false; but not for Expressions, as they have no way to represent assignment.

Comment: Yep - I think I may go down the route of trying to modify the Dynamic LINQ stuff to work with Action<T> as well as Func<T, TResult>...

Comment: Whisk - we modified dynamic LINQ a lot. (Added let and do bindings, various other features.) It compiles to Expressions, and Expressions don't have assignment.

Comment: So, basically you will need to significantly expand it. For instance, split on =, and compile each as an expression, then wireup the actual assignment/set property with codegen.

Comment: Yep, i started down that road but I think it's going to be harder than is worth it for this - it looks like .NET 4.0 is going to have an Expression.AssignField method which may help a bit...I'll give your 2 lambda idea a try and see where that goes...

Answer (score 3):

You may try this: [Dynamic Lambda Expressions Using An Isolated AppDomain](http://jp-labs.blogspot.com/2008/11/dynamic-lambda-expressions-using.html)

It compiles a lambda expression using CodeDOM compiler. In order to dispose the in-memory assembly that gets created, the compiler runs on an isolated `AppDomain`. For the passing the expression through the domain boundary, it has to be serialized. Alas, `Expression<>` is not `Serializable`. So, a trick has to be used. All the details are explained in the post.

I'm the author of that component, by the way. I would like very much to hear your feedback from it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to parse a string into a lambda expression without a full compilation, because lambda expressions can reference things that are defined outside the lambda expression. I know of no library that handles the specific case you want. There's a long discussion of this on a [thread](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2007-05/msg04019.html) on a C# discussion group.

The easiest way to get what you want is to compile a method at runtime. You can write a function that takes in the string "a.Enabled = true; return a;" and sticks that in the middle of a function that takes an Account as a parameter. I would use this [library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/runtime_eval.aspx) as a starting point, but you can also use the function mentioned on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690017/convert-complex-bool-condition-from-string-to-bool-in-net/690039#690039).

Comment: Thanks - From a quick try that doesn't seem to work when evaluating a string like "a => a.Enabled = true" to an Action<Account> delegate - am I doing something wrong or will it not work as that's not a complete c# statement on its own? I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: rossfabricant; the dynamic linq library he mentions does exactly that. Of course, you have to provide typing information when you go to compile, but it compiles just fine.

Comment: It can build queries but I didn't see that it could build anything that modifies state.

Comment: This is interesting - particularly the thread on microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp - it does seem that using Expression trees is the way forwards with this tho, I don't quite see how the dynamic compilation route will allow a simple lambda to be entered up front and get the desired results.

Comment: A lambda expression won't work, but using this approach if you know the types and number of all the arguments in advance you can factor out all the boiler plate, and the client code can just pass in a string like "a.Enabled = !a.Enabled".

Comment: Yea it could only modify state indirectly. So it could do a => a.SetEnabled(true), right?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

- Use [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to generate the module containing the "surrounding class" you'll use to build the expression; this class must implement the interface known to your application
- Use [CodeSnippedExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetexpression(VS.80).aspx) to inject the expression into its member.
- Use [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) type to create the instance of this class in runtime.

Basically, you need to build the following class with CodeDom:

```
using System;
using MyNamespace1;
using ...
using MyNamespace[N];

namespace MyNamespace.GeneratedTypes 
{
  public class ExpressionContainer[M] : IHasAccountAction
  {
    public Action<Account> AccountAction { 
      get {
        return [CodeSnippedExpression must be used here];
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Assuming that `IHasAccountAction` is:

```
public IHasAccountAction {
  public Action<Account> AccountAction { get; }
}
```

If this is done, you can get the expression compiled from string with ease. If you need its expression tree representation, use `Expression<Action<Account>>` instead of `Action<Account>` in generated type.

Comment: (replied to your comment on generic operators, btw)