# Entity Framework 4: convert a string condition to a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to accept a string array of where conditions from the client like `field == value`.
It would be really nice to create a specification object that could accept the string in the constructor and output a lambda expression to represent the Where clause.  For example, I could do the following:

```
var myCondition = new Specification<Product>( myStringArrayOfConditions); 
var myProducts = DB.Products.Where( myCondition);
```

How could you turn `"name == Jujyfruits"` into 
`DB.Products.Where(p => p.name == "JujyFruits")`?

Comment: Why can't you pass a lambda into the method, so instead of passing the string .Where("name == Jujyfruits") you pass in .Where(x => x.name == "Jujyfruits")? I don't really know what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the "specification" (where clause) comes from the client, it will be in the form of a string.  I would need to convert it in to something EF could understand, which is normally a lambda expression.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

- Reflection to get the Property `Product.name` from the string `name` and
- the LINQ `Expression` class to manually create a lambda expression.

Note that the following code example will only work for `Equals (==)` operations. However, it is easy to generalize to other operations as well (split on whitespace, parse the operator and choose the appropriate Expression instead of `Expression.Equal`).

```
    var condition = "name == Jujyfruits";

    // Parse the condition
    var c = condition.Split(new string[] { "==" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var propertyName = c[0].Trim();
    var value = c[1].Trim();

    // Create the lambda
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
    var property = typeof(Product).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var comparison = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arg, property),
        Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(comparison, arg).Compile();

    // Test
    var prod1 = new Product() { name = "Test" };
    var prod2 = new Product() { name = "Jujyfruits" };
    Console.WriteLine(lambda(prod1));  // outputs False
    Console.WriteLine(lambda(prod2));  // outputs True
```

About the constructor thing: Since `Func<T, TResult>` is sealed, you cannot derive from it. However, you could create an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) that translates `Specification<T>` into `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: So you could do something like Products.Where( p => lambda(p))?

Comment: @Dr. Zim: Actually, `Products.Where(lambda)` should be sufficient.

Comment: If you're going to go down this route, consider caching the delegate (var lambda). There is a reasonable performance hit from compiling expression trees and you definitely wouldn't want to do it prior to each search query.

Comment: @AnteSim: That depends on how you define "reasonable". Compiling the lambda in my example above takes ~5ms on my machine. I guess the database query part of the search takes significantly longer...

Comment: @Heinzi: What happens when he adapts this code to filter the search based on multiple properties? In isolation, your code is fine. But you just need to be aware that this is a point of optimisation should the need arise.

Comment: Just found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28VS.71%29.aspx, which should allow me to "convert" the where string in the specification object to the complied lambda expression implicitly.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: Thanks for the link, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I also found http://linqspecs.codeplex.com/ which is similar to what I am trying to do here. ( I think this code is much better.)

Comment: Instead of Expression.Equal, how could I figure out how to translate `p => p.Contains("something")`?  Is there a way to create a lambda delegate, then analyze how it is created?

Comment: I guess you mean `p.name.Contains("something")`. That's two member accesses (`MakeMemberAccess`): First, the `name` property of the class `Product`, then the `Contains` method of the class `String`.

Answer (score 3):

We've recently discovered the Dynamic LINQ library from the VS2008 sample projects.  Works perfectly to turn string based "Where" clauses into expressions.

[This link will get you there.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: It definitely uses a string in the where clause.  It's a good answer.  However, it produces a side effect where it changes the data type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your search term into a predicate. Try something like the following:

```
string searchString = "JujyFruits";
Func<Product, bool> search = new Func<Product,bool>(p => p.name == searchString);

return DB.Products.Where(search);
```

Comment: Would there be a way around the big switch statement testing the name of every property of Product?  Could you get a list of the "primitive" properties of Product, test against the field magic string, and construct a lambda expression where p.name is expressed as a magic string?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is trivial.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/714799/68432

Comment: http://linqspecs.codeplex.com/ is very much like your answer, which reinforces that your method is probably the generally accepted approach of making specifications first class citizens.